# Can I make ServiceStack Deserialize json value of 1 as true?

Tags: deserialization, servicestack

Can I make ServiceStack Deserialize json value of 1 as true?
Here's a unit test showing what I want to do.
Is this possible? if so how?

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool isWorking { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
[Test]
public void Deserialise1AsBoolean()
{
    var json = @"{""isWorking"": 1}";
    var myFoo = json.FromJson<Foo>();
    Assert.IsTrue(myFoo.isWorking);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Here's my solution, but please check out Mythz as well since I'm sure that will work also.

I deserialise to a custom struct `MyBool` rather than `bool`.
Here's the code for the MyBool struct.

```
public struct MyBool
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public static MyBool Parse(string value)
    {
        return new MyBool {Value = (value == "1" || value=="true")};
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(MyBool lValue)
    {
        return lValue.Value;
    }
```

and change Foo to:

```
public class Foo
{
    public MyBool isWorking { get; set; }
}
```

Criticisms welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is now [built into ServiceStack.Text with this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/d783775e25b9bd74ea9bb731c3ffc7e536873c4b) available from v3.9.55+.

Comment: I tried `JsConfig<bool>.DeSerializeFn = s => (s == "1" || s == "true");`  but I guess I'm misunderstanding how that works.

Comment: That doesn't work for built-in primitive .NET types like bool

Comment: feature request ? ;-) or is there some underlying reason it's not a good idea?