# Convert int to bool during JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, servicestack, poco

I am receiving a JSON object with RestSharp.
Therefor I've written a custom Deserializer, which implements ServiceStack.Text:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
{
  return JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>(response.Content);
}
```

The response is mapped to a POCO, which uses `System.Runtime.Serialization` to provide better mapping.
That's working fine, but not for booleans.
There are a lot of properties returned, which are 1 or 0 (ints).

For example: `{ favorite: 1 }`

The problem here is, I don't know how to convert this to a Boolean in my POCO.

This won't work (for sure):

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
  [DataMember(Name = "favorite")]
  public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get it working?

I do not only want to know this for int <=> bool, but for all type conversions in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

I've just [committed support built-in support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/d783775e25b9bd74ea9bb731c3ffc7e536873c4b) for this, so in the next version of ServiceStack.Text (v3.9.55+) you can deserialize `0`, `1`, `true`, `false` into booleans, e.g:

```
var dto1 = "{\"favorite\":1}".FromJson<Item>();
Assert.That(dto1.IsFavorite, Is.True);

var dto0 = "{\"favorite\":0}".FromJson<Item>();
Assert.That(dto0.IsFavorite, Is.False);

var dtoTrue = "{\"favorite\":true}".FromJson<Item>();
Assert.That(dtoTrue.IsFavorite, Is.True);

var dtoFalse = "{\"favorite\":false}".FromJson<Item>();
Assert.That(dtoFalse.IsFavorite, Is.False);
```

---

You can do what you want with:

```
JsConfig<bool>.DeSerializeFn = x => x.Length == 1 ? x == "1" : bool.Parse(x);
```

All of [ServiceStack.Text's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) customizations are available on [JsConfig](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs).

Other hooks available includes `JsConfig<T>.RawSerializeFn` and `JsConfig<T>.RawDeserializeFn` which lets you override the custom serialization of a custom POCO.

If you just want to some pre/post processing there's also the `JsConfig<T>.OnSerializingFn` and `JsConfig<T>.OnDeserializedFn` custom hooks.

Here's an earlier example of using a customizing deserialization using a [custom MyBool struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11075015/85785).

See the [ServiceStack.Text unit tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/tree/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests) for examples of the above custom hooks.

Comment: Hi Demis! I've built the new SS.TEXT version and use it now in my project. It works! Thanks so much for your commit! I've also tried `DeSerializeFn` which also works like a charm!

Comment: Demis, you read our minds. Just today we started to wonder about whether 0/1 values were supported for boolean deserialization.